# Flask + uwsgi: avoid Internal Server Error/"no python application found" on syntax and import errors

Tags: python, flask, exception, uwsgi

I run an internal flask app with uwsgi & nginx, set to reload every time I make changes to its files. However, whenever I accidentally save while the code is broken, the app fails to reload whenever the error in question is a SyntaxError or an ImportError, which means I have to ^C the uwsgi process and restart it.

Basically I get "no python application found" in the terminal, and an ugly unformatted "Internal server error" as html.

Is there a better way to handle all this, like an option to tell uwsgi to keep trying to reload the app?:

My uwsgi conf:

```
[uwsgi]
module = wsgi:app

master = true
processes = 5

socket = /tmp/scraper.sock
chmod-socket = 777
uid = www-data
gid = www-data
vacuum = true

die-on-term = true
plugins = python3
py-autoreload = 1
```

I run the app with `uwsgi --ini uwsgi_conf.ini` - I tried to add "--catch-exceptions" but it didn't work.

If it's of any help, my wsgi.py file as well:

```
from server import app
app.config["DEBUG"] = True
if __name__ == "__main__";
    app.run()
```